# Buck converter design review - updated

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc, dc-dc-converter, buck, converter

Last week I asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539668/how-to-create-a-high-power-buck-converter-power-supply/539825#539825) attempting to find a solution to efficiently converting higher voltage to lower voltage.

From the answers, I arrived at TI Power Designer and I ended up with this schematic.

[image]

This is all well and saved me from a lot of trouble. However, some users suggested that the layout is a lot more important than the schematic, in creating a powerful (get it?) design.

Therefore, I looked at the [datasheet of the IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54ja20.pdf?ts=1609286238518) and I started reading.

There was an example layout and some layout guidelines which I followed carefully. This resulted in adding two more bypass capacitors to the original schematic and a new schematic resulted:

[image]

After this, I started the layout for the schematic and I ended here:

[image]

This is fantastic and small, which was desired. However, I don't have a lot of experience with designing this kind of circuit so I am looking for feedback.

UPDATE:

1. Moved Rpg resistor lower as indicated by [user1850479](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/50290/user1850479) in order to tighten the loop formed by the switch, inductor, capacitor. Really useful comment. This also makes the two components more  visible (Cvcc and Rpg suggested as a DRC error by the same user)
2. As suggested by [Stiddily](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/187594/stiddily) I tightened the feedback loop by shortening the connection from 5V to the resistor and I also highlighted the path so it's more visible. Note that this is on the bottom layer.
3. Removed the adjacent nets as it seems to have confused some users. Also tried to tag the components better in the layout (picture 3) so inferring from the initial schematic (picture 1) would be easier.

Are there any other improvements I could make to this? Is there anything I could do to make the explanation of this better?

Comment: I'd get Rpg out of the way so that you can tighten up the loop formed by the switch, inductor, capacitor. It's not a high frequency part so put further out or on backside.

Comment: Are you limited to having components on one side only?

Comment: Does that layout pass DRC?  It looks to me like you have two components from VCC to GND, but the circuit diagram only shows one.

Comment: can you show the bottom layer too? Looks like your FB path goes from the via under L1 to the top left which I would recommend against. EDIT: You do show it... you're going to want to shorten that loop. Probably the second most important node.

Comment: 1) Thanks for RPG 2) No, not limited to one side and the board has 4 layers. 3) Yes, two components: Cvcc and Rpg (I added a screenshot) 4) This is the kind of essential feedback I was looking for. @Stiddily do you think I could go underneath the chip and inductor. The inductor will be shielded. I was afraid to not pick any EMI or stuff like that. I will have 2 layers of copper in between Blue and Red. What do you think?

Comment: @Andyaka I am not sure if I understand your initial question. L1 is an inductor. Has two pads. Two large pads. The indicator is in between them. Can you clarify component idents? The TI schematic (picture 1) has all component tags shown in layout (picture 3). You can infer the updated schematic (picture 2) from first schematic (picture 1) without masochism. Finally, what do you mean exactly with non-tracked connections?

Comment: No (inferring), that involves masochism. What "indicator" are you talking about? Fix it up so that component legends are visible and that the reverse view is not shown and that the thin blue nets are turned to copper (for instance, L1 does not appear to be connected to pin 20).

Comment: Now I understand. The blue nets are other components not present here (this is part of a bigger design) Edited now.

Comment: I don't like the way you routed traces between pads on some smaller SMT resistors and capacitors. It may not strictly be illegal depending on the clearance, but I would find a way to avoid that, personally.

Comment: That little circle which I think is part of the silkscreen is supposed to be near pin 1 as a pin 1 indicator. But I think you have it near pin 9 which is confusing.

Comment: @mkeith you are absolutely right about the pin 1 indicator. I missed that when I designed the footprint. Thank you a lot. Could you be more detailed about your previous comment though? It seems very general, very broad. I would really like to apply that feedback, but there's no actionable task that I can extract from the comment.

Comment: Look at Rfbb, Datasheet decoupling C1, and Cout. All three of them have a trace running between pin 1 and pin 2.  I try to avoid running traces under smaller smt components between the two pads. Like I say, it may not be a rule violation, but I don't like doing it unless I have to.